# SpringData - dynamic Mongo configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-mongo

I am working on a service where I am forced to call a service to get the connection parameters to connect to a mongo db. I've used @Configuration and a AbstractMongoConfiguration class before with static configuration variables and it worked great.

This time I am hoping there is a way to set the MongoClient configuration variables on the fly so that I can query different mongo databases on the fly. Any body know if this is possible?

Comment: Would using Spring Profiles be a good solution for you or do you need to change the MongoDB instance you want to query on the fly withou restart ?

Comment: @R4J Spring profiles would make sense, but I do need to completely change the MongoDB instance on the fly without a restart.

Comment: Then, I would say you need to wrap entire MongoDB connection related logic into some bean of yours and always obtain a connection through it. Then expose some logic through MBean/REST endpoint and on such action recreate MongoDB connection. The BIG issue would be synchronisation of all operations using MongoDB because once you trigger the 'reload' logic then you would have to wait for all threads using MongoDB connection to end and block new incoming ones until 'reload' is complete. It does show that you should think how to solve your problem without reloading on the fly :(

Comment: @R4J Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this is whats required. I'm trying to introduce spring+ java in an organization that wants to use  Scala to replace the existing .net implementation. All multi-tenancy is supported through a request to get connection details.